# E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored...” when tunning “sudo aptitude update”?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, upgrade

This is what the end of output after I run `sudo apt-get update` on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
Ign http://apt.typesafe.com unicorn/main Translation-en
35% [Working]W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/eclipse-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/eclipse-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/eclipse-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

My version of Ubuntu is 12.04.

**Update:**

I figured out dates with this command

`find /etc/apt -name '*.list' -exec bash -c 'echo -e "\n$1\n"; cat -n "$1"' _ '{}' \;`

Here is output:

/etc/apt/sources.list

```
 1  #############################################################
 2  ################### OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS ###################
 3  #############################################################
 4  
 5  ###### Ubuntu Main Repos
 6  deb http://mirror.mirohost.net/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
 7  deb-src http://mirror.mirohost.net/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
 8  
 9  ###### Ubuntu Update Repos
10  deb http://mirror.mirohost.net/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
11  deb http://mirror.mirohost.net/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
12  deb http://mirror.mirohost.net/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
13  deb-src http://mirror.mirohost.net/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
14  deb-src http://mirror.mirohost.net/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
15  deb-src http://mirror.mirohost.net/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
16  
17  ###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
18  # deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
19  # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
20  
21  ###### Ubuntu Extras Repo
22  # deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
23  # deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
24  # deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu precise main
25  # deb-src http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu precise main
```

/etc/apt/source.list

```
 1  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main universe
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-y-ppa-manager-precise.list

```
 1  # deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu precise main
 2  # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu precise main
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-talkplugin.list

```
 1  ### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
 2  # You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
 3  deb http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable main
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list

```
 1  # deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/ quantal main
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/private-ppa.launchpad.net_commercial-ppa-uploaders_intellij-idea-ce_ubuntu.list

```
 1  # deb https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/intellij-idea-ce/ubuntu precise main #Added by software-center; credentials stored in /etc/apt/auth.conf
 2  deb https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/intellij-idea-ce/ubuntu precise main #Added by software-center; credentials stored in /etc/apt/auth.conf
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-sublime-text-3-precise.list

```
 1  # deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu precise main
 2  deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu precise main
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/typesafe-apt.list

```
 1  # Typesafe repository.
 2  deb http://apt.typesafe.com/ unicorn main # Typesafe "unicorn" releases.
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/eclipse-team-ppa-precise.list

```
 1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/eclipse-team/ppa/ubuntu precise main
 2  deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/eclipse-team/ppa/ubuntu precise main
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list

```
 1  ## Please report any bug on https://bugs.launchpad.net/medibuntu/
 2  deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ precise free non-free #Medibuntu - Ubuntu 12.04 "precise pangolin"
 3  # deb-src http://packages.medibuntu.org/ precise free non-free #Medibuntu (source) - Ubuntu 12.04 "precise pangolin"
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lezhoev-qstamina-precise.list

```
 1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/lezhoev/qstamina/ubuntu precise main
 2  deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/lezhoev/qstamina/ubuntu precise main
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java-precise.list

```
 1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu precise main
 2  deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu precise main
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/tualatrix-ppa-precise.list

```
 1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu precise main
 2  deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu precise main
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kilian-f_lux-precise.list

```
 1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu precise main
 2  deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu precise main
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ppa-precise.list

```
 1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu precise main
 2  deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu precise main
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fsqcds-goldendict-precise.list

```
 1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/fsqcds/goldendict/ubuntu precise main
 2  deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/fsqcds/goldendict/ubuntu precise main
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-rhythmbox-precise.list

```
 1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/rhythmbox/ubuntu precise main
 2  deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/rhythmbox/ubuntu precise main
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/upubuntu-com-devel-precise.list

```
 1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/devel/ubuntu precise main
 2  deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/devel/ubuntu precise main
```

And I caught another snippet of trouble  at `sudo apt-get update`:

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                                                        
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                                                 
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                                                  
  404  Not Found
```

- ***How to solve this trouble?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/eclipse-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
> ```

This path does not exist on the server; apparently, the `eclipse-team` ppa doesn't offer packages for Ubuntu 12.04 "precise":

http://ppa.launchpad.net/eclipse-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/

You can solve this issue by deleting the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/eclipse-team-ppa-precise.list`:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/eclipse-team-ppa-precise.list
```

Comment: What can you say about other issues? Can you give me hints?

Comment: Is the last error still occurring? Please post the complete output of `aptitude update`, because I can't tell from that snippet which `sources.list` entry may cause that issue.

Comment: I did it and all are perfect.